# Play Framework 2.6.20 PlayService Plugin Project ApplicationLifecycle support

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I was trying out the new PlayService sbt plugin introduced with Play 2.6 (my exact Play version is 2.6.20), and I want to use the stop hook of the application as mentioned in the below link with this PlayService plugin based Play project.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up

My code looks as below,

```
@Singleton
public class LtrBootStrapper {

    @Inject
    public LtrBootStrapper(ApplicationLifecycle applicationLifecycle) {
        //Other functionalities

        //Actual components to stop inside stop hook to be added later on
        applicationLifecycle.addStopHook(() -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null));
    } 
}
```

However, when I start the application, it fails to start with the following exception.

> 1 error]  at
>   play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
>     at
>   play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>     at
>   play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:241)
>     at
>   play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:138)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$26.onPush(Ops.scala:1304)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
>   Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create
>   injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) **No implementation for play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle was bound.**
>   while locating play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
>       for the 1st parameter of com.mycompany.ltr.startup.LtrBootStrapper.(LtrBootStrapper.java:22)

Does this mean PlayService applications does not support ApplicationLifecycle? If so what is the alternative for stop hook equivalent in PlayService applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`ApplicationLifecycle`](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/playframework/playframework@df79dd9/-/blob/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.java#L19:18) is provided by [`play.inject.BuiltInModule`](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/playframework/playframework@df79dd9/-/blob/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/inject/BuiltInModule.java#L17:14). This is provided by the [java-core subproject](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d26533feb8da4dca40f7e7694886a2e4abebc719/framework/src/play-java/src/main/resources/reference.conf), which [`PlayMinimalJava`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/49570b0/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/Play.scala#L60) (and `PlayJava`) automatically adds a dependency on, but [`PlayService`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/49570b0/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/Play.scala#L19) does not.

To fix this, explicitly add the dependency to your `build.sbt`, like this:

```
libraryDependencies += javaCore
```